# How to combine 4 uint32_t ints into a whole 128 bit int and return

Tags: c, integer, bit, 128-bit

As part of a struct(let's call it ASM) in a header file there are declared four uint32_t ints.

```
uint32_t Result1; 
uint32_t Result2; 
uint32_t Result3; 
uint32_t Result4;
```

I want to access these like this: `ASM->Result1, ASM->Result2` etc and combine them into one 128 bit int with Result1 being bits 0-31 from the left, so in the end I'd have:

return 128bitint = Result1Result2Result3Result4;

How can this be done?

Comment: What data type should hold them?

Comment: even `unsigned long long` is only 64-bit I think... Perhaps you can consider using array of char t hold those results: `char a[16];`

Comment: There's a GCC extension which defines `__int128`, a 128-bit integer type that can also be unsigned. But, I don't know how portable this is or if OP has access to GCC.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd use union:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

int main(void) {
    union {
        struct {
            uint32_t v1;
            uint32_t v2;
            uint32_t v3;
            uint32_t v4;
        } __attribute__((packed));
        unsigned __int128 i128;
    } t128;
    t128.v1 = 0x22221111;
    t128.v2 = 0x44443333;
    t128.v3 = 0x66665555;
    t128.v4 = 0x88887777;

    printf("0x%016"PRIx64"%016"PRIx64"\n", (uint64_t)(t128.i128 >> 64), (uint64_t)t128.i128);

    return 0;
}
```

This gives:

```
0x88887777666655554444333322221111
```

as a result on intel (little-endian) architecture.

Comment: @chqrlie: Of course, you are right. Fixed, thank you.

Comment: Sorry, but I was not precise enough, `%lx` does not necessarily handle 64 bits (long is 32 bits on Windows even in 64 bit code).  You must either use the `PRIx64` macros or use `llx` and cast the arguments as `(unsigned long long)`: `printf("0x%016"PRIx64"%016"PRIx64"\n", (uint64_t)(t128.i128 >> 64), (uint64_t)t128.i128);` or `printf("0x%016llx%016llx\n", (unsigned long long)(uint64_t)(t128.i128 >> 64), (unsigned long long)(uint64_t)t128.i128);`

Comment: @chqrlie: Oh, I didn't know about PRIx64 macro. How useful! Thank you once again.

Comment: I am +1 ing because you mention endianness... I would just probably just return the struct for maximum portability, ie, don't worry about the union

Comment: Sadly the union trick is UB, and you're assuming no structure packing. An array of the 32 bit unsigneds and a memcpy is feasible.

Comment: @Bathsheba: Packing added.

Comment: Believe it or not, it's still UB! But perhaps bordering on pedantry.

Comment: @Bathsheba: Well, of course you are right. But this UB is 100% DB on all platforms I know.

Comment: @Bathsheba where is the UB?

Answer (score 1):

You need support for 128 bit integers for this.

with `gcc` on appropriate platforms, you can write this:

```
__uint128_t getval(const struct ASM *s) {
    return ((__uint128_t)s->Result1 <<  0) |
           ((__uint128_t)s->Result2 << 32) |
           ((__uint128_t)s->Result3 << 64) |
           ((__uint128_t)s->Result4 << 96);
}
```

Note that it is unclear what you mean by *Result1 being bits 0-31 from the left*. To clarify your specification, you must decide it `Result1` are the low order 32 bits (intel architecture, little endian, my code above), or the high order 32 bits (big endian architecture).